# Redundancies in tf.keras.backend and tensorflow libraries

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I have been working in TensorFlow for about a year now, and I am transitioning from TF 1.x to TF 2.0, and I am looking for some guidance on how to use the `tf.keras.backend` library in TF 2.0. I understand that the transition to TF 2.0 is supposed to remove a lot of redundancies in modeling and building graphs, since there were many ways to create equivalent layers in earlier TensorFlow versions (and I'm insanely grateful for that change!), but I'm getting stuck on understanding when to use `tf.keras.backend`, because the operations appear redundant with other TensorFlow libraries.

I see that some of the functions in `tf.keras.backend` are redundant with other TensorFlow libraries. For instance, `tf.keras.backend.abs` and `tf.math.abs` are not aliases (or at least, they're not listed as aliases in the documentation), but both take the absolute value of a tensor. After examining the source code, it looks like `tf.keras.backend.abs` calls the `tf.math.abs` function, and so I really do not understand why they are not aliases. Other `tf.keras.backend` operations don't appear to be duplicated in TensorFlow libraries, but it looks like there are TensorFlow functions that can do equivalent things. For instance, `tf.keras.backend.cast_to_floatx` can be substituted with `tf.dtypes.cast` as long as you explicitly specify the dtype. I am wondering two things:

1. when is it best to use the `tf.keras.backend` library instead of the equivalent TensorFlow functions?
2. is there a difference in these functions (and other equivalent `tf.keras.backend` functions) that I am missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer: Prefer tensorflow's native API such as `tf.math.*` to the`tf.keras.backend.*` API wherever possible.

Longer answer:

- The `tf.keras.backend.*` API can be *mostly* viewed as a remnant of the `keras.backend.*` API. The latter is a design that serves the "exchangeable backend" design of the original (non-TF-specific) keras. This relates to the historical aspect of keras, which supports multiple backend libraries, among which tensorflow used to be just one of them. Back in 2015 and 2016, other backends, such as Theano and MXNet were quite popular too. But going into 2017 and 2018, tensorflow became the dominant backend of keras users. Eventually keras became a part of the tensorflow API (in 2.x and later minor versions of 1.x). In the old multi-backend world, the `backend.*` API provides a backend-independent abstraction over the myriad of supported backend. But in the tf.keras world, the value of the backend API is much more limited.
- The various functions in `tf.keras.backend.*` can be divided into a few categories:

  1. Thin wrappers around the equivalent or mostly-equivalent tensorflow native API. Examples: [tf.keras.backend.less](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py#L2363), [tf.keras.backend.sin](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py#L2431)
  2. Slightly thicker wrappers around tensorflow native APIs, with more features included. Examples: [tf.keras.backend.batch_normalization](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py#L2589), [tf.keras.backend.conv2d](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py#L4869)(https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py#L4869). They often perform proprocessing and implement other logics, which make your life easier than using native tensorflow API.
  3. Unique functions that don't have equivalent in the native tensorflow API. Examples: [tf.keras.backend.rnn](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py#L3809), [tf.keras.backend.set_learning_phase](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py#L342)

For category 1, use native tensorflow APIs. For categories 2 and 3, you may want to use the `tf.keras.backend.*` API, as long as you can find it in the documentation page: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/, because the documented ones have backward compatibility guarantees, so that you don't need to worry about a future version of tensorflow removing it or changing its behavior.

Comment: Thank you! Can you also please clarify a follow up question for me: Do layers in `tf.keras.layers` use the infrastructure from `tf.keras.backend` or `tf.nn`? For instance, does `tf.keras.layers.Conv1D` use `tf.keras.backend.conv1d` or `tf.nn.conv1d`?

Comment: The internal implementation of `tf.keras.layers.*` uses a mix of `tf.keras.backend.*` APIs and native tensorflow APIs. But you shouldn't need to know or care about these internal details. They will likely change over time.

Comment: Thanks! I usually try to understand the guts, just because getting a full picture of the details helps me keep things straight in my head, but the fact that it changes with releases is a good point.

Comment: One more follow up question... do you know if there is a reason that the `tf.keras.backend` functions that you grouped into category 1 that have a one-line call to tf functions are not aliases to the equivalent tf functions? From what you've described, it sounds like it's residual from the keras API, but is there another reason?